# Ionic 4 round icon only button outside of toolbar/ion-buttons

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

How do I create a circular, clear, icon-only button outside of ion-buttons? I want to have a button with the style you get, when you use and icon-only button inside `ion-buttons` (e.g. clear and circular). 
My code so far:

```
    <ion-button icon-only shape="round" color="white" fill="clear">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
```

The resulting button isn't circular though, it's just a rectangular button with rounded corners.

The ionic 4 documentation doesn't mention how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FabButton will work... but here is how i did it in an reactjs app using ionic components, just use the angular versions and you should get the same results

```
<IonCard>
  <IonToolbar>
    <IonTitle>Test</IonTitle>
    <IonButtons slot="end">
      <IonButton
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "red",
          borderRadius: "100%",
          color: "white",
          width: 32
        }}
      >
        <IonIcon icon={close}></IonIcon>
      </IonButton>
    </IonButtons>
  </IonToolbar>
  <IonCardContent>
    This is some text that is the content of the card with the close
    button below
  </IonCardContent>
</IonCard>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to [fab button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab)

```
<ion-fab vertical="center" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
```

Comment: I am not looking for a fab-button. As far as I understood, those are meant to be fixed on a page. I want to create a close button for a `ion-card` (so that you can dismiss the card by clicking on an icon in the top right corner). If you have an icon-only button in ion-header -> ion-toolbar -> ion-buttons it looks exactly the way I want it to look. Do you have another idea?

Comment: this approach will work, just remove `vertical="center" horizontal="end" slot="fixed"`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use?

```
<ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
```

or

```
<ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the ionic css property `--border-radius` so

```
<ion-button id="closeBtn"><ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon></ion-button>
```

and in css

```
#closeBtn {
  --border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ion-fat-button to achieve that:

```
<ion-fab-button (click)="addPhotoToGallery()" color="light">
     <ion-icon name="camera-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
</ion-fab-button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this it will solve your problem.

```html
        <ion-content class="bg-image" padding>
        </ion-content>
        <ion-footer>
          <ion-toolbar>
            <button ion-button icon-only clear>
              <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button ion-button icon-only clear>
              <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-footer>
```

Comment: Use it according to your requirement.

Comment: that does not answer the question, not sure.